# Unable to click Sign in button for Microsoft Login in Java Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.name("loginfmt")).sendKeys("testauto329@gmail.com");  
driver.findElement(By.className("button_primary")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("i0118")).sendKeys("test@123");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

Using the above line of code was trying to sign-in but action is performing and stuck at the password page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Webdriver wait before entering the password and before clicking the sign in Button

[WebDriver Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: Also provide the error you're getting and screenshots

Comment: Thanks for the response and was able to go up for the next page but again getting stuck at the email verification page

Comment: Could you provide the errors you're getting and provide more details about the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try by applying selenium's `waits`. Replace the below line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

With:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"))).click();
```